# Return a table and relationships result on REST API request using codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I m having a trouble how can i show or display a table with  multiple relationships to be returned with its relation inteadt of the table / user only.

Forexample:

I have Publication Table and Issue Table ..related to **1-Publication can Have multiple/many-ISSUES.**
And , when i wanted to load for example

> http://restapi.url/publications/format/json

I wanted to see Publication and also all related Issues on code igniter. This my code on my Controller..

```
function publications_get(){
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('publication');
        $return = $this->db->get();

       if( $return!= null ) {

           $this->response($return->result_array(),200); //success
       } else {

           $this->response(NULL,404);
       }
```

Juts to be like this :

```
<officer id="1">
   <name>James T. Kirk</name>
   <rank>Captain</rank>
   <subordinates>
      <link ref="http://ncc1701/api/officers/2">
      <link ref="http://ncc1701/api/officers/3">
   </subordinates>
</officer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use two queries, one for all publications (like now) and for every issues by publication

```
function publications_get(){
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('publication');
        $return = $this->db->get();
        $publications = $return->result_array(); //success
        foreach($publications as $index => $publication){
            $publications[$index]['issues'] = issues_get($publication['id']);
        }
         $this->response($publications,200);
}
```

Getting the issues in publication

```
function issues_get($id_publication){
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('isssues');
        $this->db->where('id_publication', $id_publication);
        $return = $this->db->get();
        $this->response($return->result_array(),200); //success
}
```